# What happens if compiler inlines a function which is called through a function pointer

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction

Let us say I have a function in my program and somewhere in my code, that function is called through a function pointer. What happens if the compiler happened to inline that function, or would the compiler realize that there is a function pointer assigned to that function and therefore avoid inlining it.

Comment: See Herb Sutter's [Inline Redux](http://www.drdobbs.com/inline-redux/184403879).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When a pointer to a function is taken, the compiler will generate an out-of-line body for the function. It is still possible to inline the function at other call sites.

Note that a function marked `inline` must have a definition available in all TUs which refer to it, and these definitions must be identical. Which means it's perfectly safe to inline the function at some call sites and keep it out-of-line at others.

Comment: What happens if the definitions aren't identical (eg some ifdef'd code), and the linker gets multiple versions of the function? The 'inline' is presumably seen by the linker as a weak symbol, and you just get the first one that comes up?

Comment: @NicholasWilson that'd be an illformed program.

Comment: @NicholasWilson that would be a violation of the one-definition rule, and it is explicitly called out as having no defined behaviour.

Comment: @NicholasWilson In such case, [basic.def.odr] §5 states "then the behaviour is undefined."

Answer (score 4):

Well, it will surely work. I don't see how inlining would prevent that. You just have some code that calls the function directly, and it might be inlined there, and you have some code which calls it through a function pointer, just as a regular function.

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason that using a function pointer should prevent inlining. Inlining is done on a case-by-case basis and can exist alongside a usual function body. So a function can be inlined in one place, and called in another.

The compiler will, therefore, inline where it can and still produce a callable function for your function pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Not only does the compiler inline "other calls of the function", but it may even inline calls through function pointers if it understands enough about which function is actually being used, something like this:

```
typedef void (*funcptr)();

void somefunc()
{
   ... do stuff here ... 
}

void indirection(funcptr *f)
{
   f();
}

void call_with_ptr()
{
    funcptr f = somefunc();
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
       indirection(f);
    }
}
```

I had code similar to this, and it inlined the indirection, and made the call to somefunc() a direct call without using the function pointer.

But of course, this assumes the compiler can figure out which function is called from the code - which is obvious in this case, but if there is runtime decisions involved, it may not do so.